# error with playing mp3 file with python os

Tags: python, operating-system, mp3

I'm using os.startfile code to run   .mp3 file but there is an error:

my code is

```
os.system("Warning.mp3")
```

but i get an error like this,

```
sh: Warning.mp3: command not found
```

can you help me about starting mp3 file using os.startfile?

Comment: Are you actually using `os.startfile` or are you instead using `os.system` as your post suggests?

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` makes a call to the system shell to execute the argument you pass.
Therefore you get an error message from the shell `sh` saying that `Warning.mp3` is not a command. If you want it to play from shell execution you need to pass it a command which can play a file such as this such as `mpg123` on ubuntu/debian (make sure its installed). To invoke this from python:

```
os.system("mpg123 Warning.mp3")
```

See the documentation on the `os.system()` function for more details.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: I'm not familiar with mac, however a quick google search revealed that there may be a built in program called `afplay` which plays mp3 files. So replace `mpg123` with that program and give it a shot.

By the way you didn't specify what the application is for this, but this may not be the implementation. This will call an external function in the shell to play music, and playback will be controlled by that program, not python. I haven't used it myself, but theres a python package called `playsound` you might want to check out.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1